# React Stripe Integration: Getting a 404 Error when Attempting to Create a Checkout Session

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

I'm currently working on integrating Stripe into my React application to handle payments for different products. However, I'm encountering a 404 error when trying to create a checkout session using the Stripe API.

Here's an overview of the setup:

Frontend: I have a React component called PurchaseButton that renders buttons with different prices (e.g., $5, $10, $15, $20). When a user clicks on any of these buttons, it triggers a fetch request to the server to create a Stripe checkout session.

Backend: I have set up a Node.js server using Express to handle the server-side logic. The server has a route /create-checkout-session that receives a POST request with the selected product's price ID from the frontend. It then uses the Stripe API to create a checkout session.

However, when I click on any of the buttons, the fetch request fails with a 404 error, indicating that the /create-checkout-session route is not found. I've double-checked the route definition on the server and confirmed that the server is running on the correct port (5173).

Here's the relevant code:

account.jsx

```
// ... (Other imports and components)
import PurchaseButton from "../content/PurchaseButton";

function Account() {
  // ... (Auth0 logic)

  if (isAuthenticated) {
    return (
      <div className="accountwrapper">
        <PurchaseButton Cost={5} priceId="price_1NVK0XLRRt3tMlsEjx4N4H4v" />
        <PurchaseButton Cost={10} priceId="price_1NVT9gLRRt3tMlsEEGljqqLK" />
        <PurchaseButton Cost={15} priceId="price_1NVTB5LRRt3tMlsEPEa6jh85" />
        <PurchaseButton Cost={20} priceId="price_1NVTBcLRRt3tMlsE1dN3X2Lm" />
      </div>
    );
  }

  return null;
}
```

purchasebutton.jsx

```
import React from "react";

const stripeApiKey = "sk_test_..."; // My Stripe API key

function PurchaseButton({ Cost, priceId }) {
  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5173/create-checkout-session", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ priceId }),
      });

      if (response.ok) {
        // ... (Redirect to Stripe checkout)
      } else {
        console.error("Error creating checkout session");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error sending request:", error);
    }
  };

  // ... (Button rendering)
}

export default PurchaseButton;
```

server.cjs

```
const stripe = require("stripe")("sk_test_..."); // My Stripe API key

const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static("public"));

const YOUR_DOMAIN = "http://localhost:5173";

app.use(express.json());

app.post("/create-checkout-session", async (req, res) => {
  const { priceId } = req.body;
  try {
    // ... (Create Stripe checkout session)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error creating checkout session:", error.message);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Failed to create checkout session" });
  }
});

app.listen(5173, () => console.log("Running on port 5173"));
```

I've double-checked all the configurations, and the API key is correct. Additionally, CORS is configured correctly on the server. Despite this, I'm still encountering the 404 error when attempting to create a checkout session.

Can someone please help me identify the issue and provide a solution? Thank you in advance for any assistance!

Comment: Try sending POST /create-checkout-session request from curl or Postman or similar tool - to verify that backend works properly

Comment: I get no errors when running all of the code that you've provided. It all works just fine for me running on my machine. Have you tried just reproducing the problem with the details you've provided in your question? Is there anything else going on that we should know about? I can't reproduce it.

Comment: Flagging that you're using your secret API key (`sk_•••`) in your client-side code.  You should only use your publishable API key (`pk_•••`) client-side and treat your secret API key as you would a sensitive password.